Importing module error: module does not provide an export named default/{module name}
I have a script named /src/web/static/js/my_vue_widget.js. It looks like this:
const MyVueWidget = {
    name: 'MyVueWidget',
    ...
};
export default MyVueWidget;

I have an HTML /src/web/static/templates/index.html  which tries to import the Vue component from that JavaScript.
import {MyVueWidget} from '/static/js/my_vue_widget.js';

##Also tried these varaitions with no better results:
#import MyVueWidget from '/static/js/my_vue_widget.js';
#import MyVueWidget from './static/js/my_vue_widget.js';
#import {MyVueWidget} from './static/js/my_vue_widget.js';

In my FastAPI app's main.py I have:
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
app.mount("/templates", tmplts, name="templates")

When this page is being rendered, in the console I see the following JavaScript error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/static/js/my_vue_widget.js' does not provide an export named 'MyVueWidget' (at (index):142:17)


Did you add type="module" to the script tag?

@GuerricP yes, that is there

According to me import MyVueWidget from '/static/js/my_vue_widget.js'; should work

@mike01010 what is the error is you use import with a defaultExport syntax:
import MyVueWidget from '/static/js/my_vue_widget.js'; ?

The question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, please, list entire files and parts instead of excerpts, it's unclear what type="module" looks like. It should be import MyVueWidget ..., there's no room for guesswork, this import is correct and others aren't
